# Count characters of input and increment a variable after x characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding AngularJS to a project and need to count the length of a textarea, incrementing the total number of "pages" (messaging app) every 160 characters - and decrementing if text is deleted.

Getting the length of the textarea with Angular is simple:

```
<textarea ng-model="message" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
<span class="help-block"><strong>Characters</strong>: <% message.length > 0 ? message.length : 0 %></span>
```

I'm guessing the best place to handle the logic to determine the number of pages would be in my Javascript code but I cannot figure out how to link the `ng-model` to my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42543/simplifying-an-angularjs-directive-that-counts-the-number-of-characters-entered. I do like the validated answer

Comment: Evandro - you have me on the right track. Answering my own question, let me know what you think. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an ng-change, you can just do it in the dom directly:

```
 <textarea ng-model="message" class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
 <span class="help-block"><strong>Characters</strong>: {{ (message.length - message.length % 160) / 160 + 1 }}</span>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EEMd3/

**edit**

To include other details just simple add them in to the calculation:

```
{{ (message.length - message.length % 160 + user.name + agency.nickname + ...) / 160 + 1 }}
```

Comment: I really like this but there is one part that I forgot about that ng-change seems to help with. Each outgoing message has the agency nickname, user's name, and `@user` tag. So the actual string length I need to measure is the entire thing - appended text plus what is entered into the textarea. If you can show me how to do this just in Angular that would rock!

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks for this, much more eloquent than what I put together

Answer (score 0):

With help from Evandro Silva - using `ng-change`:

```
$scope.change = function(length)
        {
            $scope.pages = Math.round(length / 160) + 1;
        }

<textarea ng-model="message" class="form-control" ng-change="change(message.length)" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
<span class="help-block"><strong>Characters</strong>: <% message.length > 0 ? message.length : 0 %></span>
```

Comment: Looks perfectly reasonable. You might want to send the whole message to an `onChange` handler rather than just the length because it's likely you'll want to do something else with it in the future (color the letters that are too long in red, limit typing after a while, etc)

Comment: Math.round was actually causing issues, `parseInt()` seems to fit the bill better. Basically, this is a form input that will be the body of an outgoing SMS message. So the user needs to know how many messages will be sent for their own message body - split at 160 characters. So this lets them fine tune their message to avoid multiple SMS messages.
However, could you give me an example of how to send the whole message to a handler? Thanks!

Comment: `ng-change="onChange(message)"`. `$scope.onChange = function(text) { text.length... }`